# More Efficient Than A Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Hi I have a massive case statement and I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing it than the way I have used. The code works fine on my data just wanted to know if a better way that would be easier to produce or run faster.

```
    SELECT [FileName]
    ,[sheetname]
    ,CASE
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL1' + '_' +  'VAL2' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL3' + '_' +  'VAL4' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL5' + '_' +  'VAL6' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL7' + '_' +  'VAL8' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL9' + '_' +  'VAL10' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL11' + '_' +  'VAL12' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL13' + '_' +  'VAL14' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL15' + '_' +  'VAL16' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL17' + '_' +  'VAL18' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL19' + '_' +  'VAL20' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL21' + '_' +  'VAL22' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL23' + '_' +  'VAL24' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL25' + '_' +  'VAL26' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL27' + '_' +  'VAL28' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL29' + '_' +  'VAL30' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL31' + '_' +  'VAL32' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL33' + '_' +  'VAL34' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL35' + '_' +  'VAL36' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL37' + '_' +  'VAL38' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL39' + '_' +  'VAL40' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL41' + '_' +  'VAL42' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL43' + '_' +  'VAL44' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL45' + '_' +  'VAL46' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL47' + '_' +  'VAL48' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL49' + '_' +  'VAL50' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL51' + '_' +  'VAL52' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL53' + '_' +  'VAL54' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL55' + '_' +  'VAL56' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL57' + '_' +  'VAL58' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL59' + '_' +  'VAL60' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL61' + '_' +  'VAL62' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL63' + '_' +  'VAL64' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL65' + '_' +  'VAL66' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL67' + '_' +  'VAL68' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL69' + '_' +  'VAL70' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL71' + '_' +  'VAL72' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL73' + '_' +  'VAL74' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL75' + '_' +  'VAL76' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL77' + '_' +  'VAL78' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL79' + '_' +  'VAL80' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL81' + '_' +  'VAL82' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL83' + '_' +  'VAL84' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL85' + '_' +  'VAL86' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL87' + '_' +  'VAL88' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL89' + '_' +  'VAL90' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL91' + '_' +  'VAL92' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL93' + '_' +  'VAL94' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL95' + '_' +  'VAL96' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL97' + '_' +  'VAL98' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL99' + '_' +  'VAL100' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL101' + '_' +  'VAL102' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL103' + '_' +  'VAL104' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL105' + '_' +  'VAL106' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL107' + '_' +  'VAL108' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL109' + '_' +  'VAL110' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL111' + '_' +  'VAL112' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL113' + '_' +  'VAL114' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL115' + '_' +  'VAL116' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL117' + '_' +  'VAL118' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL119' + '_' +  'VAL120' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL121' + '_' +  'VAL122' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL123' + '_' +  'VAL124' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL125' + '_' +  'VAL126' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL127' + '_' +  'VAL128' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL129' + '_' +  'VAL130' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL131' + '_' +  'VAL132' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL133' + '_' +  'VAL134' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL135' + '_' +  'VAL136' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL137' + '_' +  'VAL138' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL139' + '_' +  'VAL140' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL141' + '_' +  'VAL142' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL143' + '_' +  'VAL144' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL145' + '_' +  'VAL146' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL147' + '_' +  'VAL148' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL149' + '_' +  'VAL150' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL151' + '_' +  'VAL152' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL153' + '_' +  'VAL154' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL155' + '_' +  'VAL156' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL157' + '_' +  'VAL158' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL159' + '_' +  'VAL160' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL161' + '_' +  'VAL162' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL163' + '_' +  'VAL164' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL165' + '_' +  'VAL166' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL167' + '_' +  'VAL168' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL169' + '_' +  'VAL170' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL171' + '_' +  'VAL172' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL173' + '_' +  'VAL174' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL175' + '_' +  'VAL176' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL177' + '_' +  'VAL178' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL179' + '_' +  'VAL180' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL181' + '_' +  'VAL182' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL183' + '_' +  'VAL184' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL185' + '_' +  'VAL186' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL187' + '_' +  'VAL188' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL189' + '_' +  'VAL190' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL191' + '_' +  'VAL192' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL193' + '_' +  'VAL194' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL195' + '_' +  'VAL196' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL197' + '_' +  'VAL198' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL199' + '_' +  'VAL200' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL201' + '_' +  'VAL202' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL203' + '_' +  'VAL204' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL205' + '_' +  'VAL206' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL207' + '_' +  'VAL208' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL209' + '_' +  'VAL210' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL211' + '_' +  'VAL212' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL213' + '_' +  'VAL214' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL215' + '_' +  'VAL216' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL217' + '_' +  'VAL218' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL219' + '_' +  'VAL220' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL221' + '_' +  'VAL222' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL223' + '_' +  'VAL224' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL225' + '_' +  'VAL226' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL227' + '_' +  'VAL228' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL229' + '_' +  'VAL230' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL231' + '_' +  'VAL232' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] =  'VAL233' + '_' +  'VAL234' THEN [SHORTNAME]
    END AS SHORTNAME

    ,CASE
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT1%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT1'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT2%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT2'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT3%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT3'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    WHEN  [SheetName] LIKE  '%SOME_TEXT%' THEN 'SOME_MORE_TEXT'
    END AS SOME_MORE_TEXT

    ,CASE
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_10426%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_12135%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_17251%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_2585X%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_33466%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_43788%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_44935%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_52607%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_56665%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_61659%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_68605%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_75543%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_78984%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_81633%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_89264%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_C5649%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_C6020%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_E2930%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_G1255%' THEN SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)
    END AS SUBFILENAME

    ,CASE
         WHEN [Branch] = 'L364X' THEN 'L364X'
    WHEN [Branch] = 'K4373' THEN 'K4373'
    WHEN [Branch] = 'AD015' THEN 'AD015'
    WHEN [Branch] = '38154' THEN '38154'
    WHEN [Branch] = '35669' THEN '35669'
    WHEN [Branch] = 'K4388' THEN 'K4388'
    WHEN [Branch] = 'A4360' THEN 'A4360'
    WHEN [Branch] = '8932X' THEN '8932X'
    WHEN [Branch] = 'E0530' THEN 'E0530'
    END AS Branch

    INTO T2
    FROM T1
```

sorry the first case statement is not right it should be more like this but for the same amount of rows just different data for each line

```
    SELECT   [FileName]
    ,[SheetName]
    ,CASE   WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] = 'Adhoc Feed Data_Castaways ONEShop' THEN 'Castaw'
            WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] = 'Adhoc Feed Data_Sol World Spar' THEN 'SolSpr'
            WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] = 'Adhoc Feed Data_Sunway CoOp' THEN 'SunCO'
```

Comment: Why do you write `'VAL1' + '_' +  'VAL2'` instead of `'VAL1_VAL2'`? Also, you are always assigning `SHORTNAME`, so a single `WHEN` would be sufficient: `WHEN [FileName] + '_' + [SheetName] IN('VAL1_VAL2','VAL3_VAL4',...)`

Comment: they are two separate columns and so I can read the values better when run

Comment: But they aren't columns but string literals.

Comment: yes strings contained within filename and sheetname, sorry just seen my mistake, [shortname] should be 'shortname'

Comment: is it quicker to store the values of [filename] & [sheetname] rather than building on the fly? so it would be 

        WHEN [FileName]+[sheetname] = [filesheet] THEN 'castaw'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is the same as

```
case when Left(FileName,3) = 'VAL' 
       And IsNumeric(SUbstring(FileName, 4,5)) = 1 
       And cast(SUbstring(FileName, 4,5) as integer) Between 1 and 123
       And Left(SheetName,3) = 'VAL' 
       And IsNumeric(SUbstring(SheetName, 4,5)) = 1 
       And cast(SUbstring(SheetName, 4,5) as integer) Between 1 and 123
     then Shortname end shortname
```

The second one, If I understand what you are trying to do correctly), is the same as

```
Replace(FileName, 'SOME_TEXT', 'SOME_MORE_TEXT')
```

The third one could be replaced with

```
case when Left(FileName, 4) = 'ATE_' 
        And substring(FileName,5,5) in ('10426', '12135', ... , 'G1255') 
     then substring(FileName,5,5) end as subFileName
```

etc.

Comment: thanks for your answers, the third one will work brilliantly, but haven't put the correct values in the first or second examples just made them up to show what I have done. The second example you have given does not assign the replacement text to another column it just replaces the sheetname where I need it in another column.

Comment: I am just trying to adapt your first example to see if I can use it, I shall let you know, thanks again for your help very much appreciated @Charles Bretana

Comment: The first case appears to always return shortname so why not SELECT ..., ShortName, .....

Comment: I have changed it @steveford I had put a column where should of put a string given example of proper data just below. Thank tho Steve